# No command builder registered for name extractHBaseCells

Tags: hadoop, solr, hbase, bigdata

I am trying to index data from HBase to Solr and using Hbase-Indexer for the same.
But I am getting "No command builder registered for name: extractHBaseCells" any suggestions.

My morphline.conf is

```
morphlines : [{ id : morphline1    importCommands : ["org.kitesdk.morphline.**", "com.ngdata.**"]    
    commands :
    [{extractHBaseCells 
        { mappings : [ 
        {inputColumn : "data:*" 
        outputField : "data" type : string  source : value} ]}} 
       {logTrace { format : "output record: {}", args : ["@{}"] } } 
     ] }]
```

and hbase-indexer.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <indexer table="trialll" mapper="com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.morphline.MorphlineResultToSolrMapper" mapping-type="column">   
          <param name="morphlineFile" value="/home/yash/Desktop/morphline.conf"/>
     </indexer>
```